# Minimum and max of two column

Tags: sql-server

I want to find the minimum value present in 2 columns and max value present in 2 column
EX: A :2 3 4
    B: 5 6 7

Ans should be 2 for min and 7 for max.
A and B are columns in same table.
 min() inbuilt function doesn't exists.

Comment: and what is giving you difficulty achieving that?

Comment: was `A` and `B` your tables? If so, can you add their column definitions?

Comment: @kaira are there other columns in select statement.if so place them in group statement at end.

Comment: A and B are column names in same table

Comment: What do you mean when you say "min() inbuilt function doesn't exist?"  That's a basic available function in every major DBMS, and has been for many years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-contained example.

```
declare @t table(a int, b int)
insert into @t values(2,5)
insert into @t values(3,6)
insert into @t values(4,7)

select min(a) as a,max(b) as b from @t

--if for some reason min() and max() are 'not available' (???)
select
  (select top 1 a from @t order by a asc) as a
 ,(select top 1 b from @t order by a desc) as b
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest way is `apply`:

```
select min(x.val), max(x.val)
from t cross apply
     (select val
      from (values (t.col1), (t.col2)) v(val)
     ) x;
```

The `cross apply` simply unpivots the values into a single column, before running the aggregation functions.

Comment: Or you could UNION

Comment: @RafalZiolkowski You could, but it involves reading from the source table twice, whereas this method only reads once. If you were to use `UNION` then you should at the very least use `UNION ALL`, removing duplicates before selecting min or max is a needless and expensive step.

Comment: Am I missing something?  Why do you need cross apply when just min() and max() are sufficient?

Comment: @JosephStyons . . . Because the two values need to be in the same column.  This isn't taking a separate `min()` and `max()` of the two columns.  It is combining the two columns into a single column and then calculating the aggregation functions.

Answer (score 2):

You could go with:

```
SELECT MIN(val), MAX(val) FROM (
  SELECT a val FROM Table
  UNION
  SELECT b FROM Table
) d
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is indexing which is appropriate, it might be more efficient to do the MIN/MAX independently first on columns A and B since it would hopefully use some seeks into appropriate indexes on those columns:

```
SELECT MIN(mn), MAX(mx)
FROM (
    SELECT MIN(A) AS mn, MAX(A) AS mx FROM tbl
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MIN(B) AS mn, MAX(B) AS mx FROM tbl
) x;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use Max and Min function to determine the max n min values for that column.

```
  Select Min(A),Max(B) from Table
```